# Windows Time Zone Abbreviations in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, windows, timezone

Do they even exist? I am really sick of having to display "Romance Standard Time" to my European users and trying to explain why their "Central European Time" can't be displayed as "CET". If I parsed "Romance Standard Time" and presented them with "RST" that would be meaningless to them, or possibly confused as "Russian Standard Time" or other nonsense.

Is there not a way to get generally accepted abbreviations out of Windows? I need something that works across North America, South America, Europe, Africa, and Asia.

**UPDATE: This is a total hack, I know, but it will likely get me 90% of the cases I care about. If you have suggestions, I'm still all ears ;)**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current time zone abbreviation, corrected for Daylight Saving Time (if applicable)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeZoneId">The time zone id.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetTZAbbrev(string timeZoneId)
    {
      var timeZoneInfos = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
      var abbrev = string.Empty;

      foreach (var timeZoneInfo in timeZoneInfos)
      {
        if (timeZoneInfo.Id != timeZoneId) continue;

        string[] words;

        if (timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.UtcNow))
        {
          words = timeZoneInfo.DaylightName.Split(' ');         
        }
        else
        {
          words = timeZoneInfo.StandardName.Split(' ');         
        }

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
          abbrev += word[0];
        }
      }
      return abbrev;
    }
```

Comment: NodaTime is now avialble http://nodatime.org/

Answer (score 6):

Well, even the "generally accepted abbreviations" aren't really a good idea - because they're so ambiguous. If you say "EDT" do you mean Eastern Daylight Time in the US, or Eastern Daylight Time in Australia?

A more generally accepted *technical* solution is to use Olson (zoneinfo) names such as "Europe/London" as identifiers. How these are presented to users is a different matter, but usually I see user interfaces with place names for particular time zones along with their standard (or current; it varies) offset from UTC. See Google Calendar's time zone settings for example.

This is really a matter of internationalizing (or localizing, I can never remember) identifiers to user-friendly names, however you do it.

Comment: Agreed, but Windows does not use the Olson DB natively. It's a bunch of shit^H^H^H^H data stored in the registry only accessible via APIs as far as I've been able to deduce.

Comment: @Mark: But that has nothing to do with using the abbreviations. That's just a matter of Windows not using the same identifiers as zoneinfo. (Something which Noda Time will fix when I get round to completing v1, by the way.)

Comment: Noda Time looks great, but I can't wait around that long ;) I think I'll just split/join on the TZ name and create the abbreviation that way. i.e. "Central European Summer Time" => "CEST". When they bitch at me about "RST", I'll just have to explain to them that it's a technical constraint they'll have to live with ;)

Comment: +1, `CST` is another good example http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/

Comment: @Jodrell: Why is AMT a better example? In fact, EDT shows up in that list as *three* different options...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, excuse the interruption.

Answer (score 1):

You could always build a crosswalk method and convert them yourself.  You would just need to get a list of each time, then crosswalk it yourself.  I don't know of anything in windows that has this for you, but you're not talking a lot of code to do it yourself...

Comment: Yeah I suppose I could. I was just venting angrily that our "friends" at Microsoft have not yet solved this obvious (IMHO) problem that "just works" on UNIX systems.