# C# Parse string to date in the following format 19 March 2014 10:32:04 CEST

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, date

I am trying to convert strings to dates in the format below. I would like to keep the timezone format such that when i retrieve it from the DB it will be parsed to the correct time.

Another example of the string i receive is "19 March 2014 10:32:04 GMT";

```
`string date = "19 March 2014 10:32:04 CEST";
 Console.WriteLine(date);
 DateTimeOffset result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);' `
```

This is for a .net API

Thanks

Dan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879817/c-sharp-parse-gmt-date-string-to-datetime

Comment: and a more detailed explanation of why your plan is flawed, from a man who knows, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195948/windows-time-zone-abbreviations-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is, you can't do it.

---

Here is why,

There is a definitive database of world timezones, you can get it from the [IANA here](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).

The problem is, the 3 or 4 letter abbreviations have a many-to-one association with the IANA timezones. For instance [`"AMT"`](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/) means different things, depending on your culture or what part of the world you are in.

```
AMT "Armenia Time Asia"         UTC + 4 hours 
AMT "Amazon Time South America" UTC - 4 hours
```

If you really want to tackle this, I suggest using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) to represent your `Instance`s. You'll have to write some code to convert the abbreviations to a standard IANA timezone.

**We can't do this for you, it depends on the context of your application.**

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Basically i am parsing an email body and this is the format for the date. Unfortunately i have no control over the format. I can save the information to the date fine however without the timezone information our mobile apps that's consume the date through the api are unable to show correct time

Comment: @Dan perhaps you can map the timezone abbreviations in the supplied data one-to-one with a subset of IANA timezones.